# How to do indexing in hibernate3

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, indexing

I am newbie to hibernate framework.To increase the performance of searching in my project i want to do index for some tables columns.As per my research,hibernate automatically indexes when performing crud operations via criteria.so is their any way to tune my search faster in hibernate and also creating index externally increase the performance of my search?

Any Idea will be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URL:

http://hibernate.org/search/documentation/getting-started/#define-which-entities-need-to-be-indexed

Can give you details on indexing n hibernate.

Below is some snippet from the link. For furter reading, please refer the link.

The annotation @Indexed marks Book as an entity which needs to be indexed by Hibernate Search.

```
package example;
...
@Entity
@Indexed
public class Book {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Integer id;

  @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO)
  private String title;

  @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO)
  private String subtitle;

  @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.NO, store=Store.YES)
  @DateBridge(resolution=Resolution.DAY)
  private Date publicationDate;

  @IndexedEmbedded
  @ManyToMany
  private Set<Author> authors = new HashSet<Author>();
  public Book() {
  }

  // standard getters/setters follow here
  ...
}
```

Comment: Did you wrote the index for book in your db or else you just put @Indexed annotation in java class automatically consider this table as index.

Comment: You just put @Indexed annotation in java class and hibernate automatically consider this table as index.